# Are "Reverse DNS" string names copyrighted?

Tags: reverse-dns

Are the PTR records for IP addresses copyrighted by anyone?  For example, WHOIS data is copyrighted by ARIN and other regional registries (http://www.ripe.net/db/support/db-terms-conditions.html). WHOIS data is different than rDNS data, I'm wondering about the rDNS data specifically...

Comment: This isn't really sysadmin related.  At the very minimum it should be community wiki.

Answer (score 2):

IANAL, but I suspect that copyright could not be applied to a specific record any more than you can copyright a phone number, or an address.

As I understand it, in the US, usually you can not copyright individual facts, but you can copyright a database of facts if the database has some degree of creativity.  ([Ref](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feist_Publications_v._Rural_Telephone_Service))

It is likely that trademarks will cover many of the domain names that are part of a PTR record.

I have no idea why it would matter to you though.  If it does you should probably [ask a lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613396/how-do-you-find-a-lawyer-who-is-able-to-answer-software-development-questions).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about copyrighted, but I'd say they're owned by the company that owns the domain.